# Gambling puzzle

Tags: probability, combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

A math friend of mine showed me this strange gambling puzzle.  There is a button in a casino and every time you press it you can win either $1$ or $0$ dollars. The probability of winning $1$ dollar depends on how many times you have pressed it so far.  If you press it for the $x$-th time you have probability $x/M$ of winning a dollar. If $x$ gets to $M$ or greater then you just win a dollar every time.

How many button presses do you expect to have to press to win $N$ dollars?

Comment: When you say 'how many times you have pressed it so far', do you mean 'since the last time you earned a dollar' or 'since you started pressing'?  Both are relatively straightforward to solve, but they have very different solutions...

Comment: I mean `since you started pressing'.

Comment: Where is this casino?

Answer (score 2):

**Caution:** This answer is WRONG. But I leave it here since my mistake may help to understand the question correctly. See edit in the last.

Suppose you play $L$ times. If $L > M$ then you will get
$$ \begin{align*}
E(L) &= \frac{1}{M} + \frac{2}{M} + \cdots + \frac{M}{M} + 1 + \cdots + 1 \\
&= \frac{1}{2}(M + 1) + (L - M)
\end{align*}$$
dollars. Otherwise you will get
$$ \begin{align*}
E(L) &= \frac{1}{M} + \frac{2}{M} + \cdots + \frac{L}{M} \\
&= \frac{1}{2M}L(L + 1)
\end{align*}$$
dollars. Hence, all you need to do is solve $E(L) = N$ for $L$: the answer would be
$$L = \begin{cases}
N + \frac{M - 1}{2} \qquad \left(N > \frac{1 + M}{2}\right) \\
\frac{-1 + \sqrt{1 + 8MN}}{2} \qquad \left(N \leq \frac{1 + M}{2}\right).
\end{cases}$$

**Edit I:** Thanks to Steven Stadnicki, I realize I was completely wrong. Even in case $N > M$, the expected value is
$$ N \frac{M!}{M^M} + \sum_{k = 1}^{M - 1} (N + k) \frac{M!}{M^M} \sum_{0 < n_1 < \cdots < n_k < M} \prod_{i = 1}^k \frac{M - n_i}{n_i} $$
but I cannot get its simpler form.

**Edit II:** I conduct a [computational experiment](http://aleph.sagemath.org/?z=eJx1kU1uwyAQhfecYqpsILVELFVdVPHSS_sOjgINkhnQmKTk9sHFaXCiskHz8x7fDJs3eZ5IHgxKhRfw13ByyJgmZ4EGPKbLWO8o3KNhArowdlQaPLkDjxV04ovBckiFMyFYg7yuQI9uCDwK2YksCWSGkXcV9IXGOlRXaGD3l4mr6OdkRrV07aF_CB_t7w3UL2mjEyoXsG9K1MVopVioY4ZU0SsyVmH4Ja0y9dTUu-32o-BuV5TaEQQwySVt6lvxLBKvtO38drGIZ4q8tFbI7JA-Izl3s3M2Tnv9LGznav9v9X48GQyQx3maT7Abj2yEBQ==&lang=python) and get the average values for $10^4$ trials to guess the expected value $E(M, N)$ as follow.
$$\begin{array}{l|lllll}
M \backslash N & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\hline \\
1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
2 & 1.5 & 2.5 & 3.5 & 4.5 & 5.5 \\
3 & 1.9 & 3.0 & 4.0 & 5.0 & 6.0 \\
4 & 2.2 & 3.5 & 4.5 & 5.5 & 6.5 \\
5 & 2.5 & 3.9 & 5.0 & 6.0 & 7.0
\end{array}$$

Comment: Is "At what point do my expected winnings become N" the same question as "What is the expected number of plays to reach winnings of N"?  I believe that independence (assuming that the results _are_ independent, which comes down to the problem description) may save you here, but generically I thought it wasn't _quite_ that easy...

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your comment correctly. Do you suggest the answer should be not expected number of plays but the _distribution_ of the expected number of plays?

Comment: No, I'm saying that 'the turn where the EV of your winnings becomes N' isn't (I think) necessarily the same thing as 'the EV of the turn where your winnings become N'.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: I get your point. Yes, it is most likely that my answer is wrong and proper one is far difficult than my first impression.

Comment: @Taro It's not as wrong as you think. The $N> (1+M)/2$ case seem to be perfect and the other case is *almost* right it seems.

Comment: @clink31: I do some experiment. And it seems that you are right. The result fits though I'm not sure why the numbers coincides.

Comment: You seem to be using $L$ to refer to "the amount of money I win after $L$ plays"....

Comment: @Hurkyl: I use $E(L)$ to refer to "the amount of money I win after $L$ plays".

Comment: @Taro For exact values, the row for $M=3$ should be $17/9, 3, 4,5, 6$ and for $M=4$ it is $71/32, 111/32, 9/2, 11/2,  13/2$ and for $M=5$ it is $1569/625, 2437/625, 3119/625, 6, 7$.

Comment: @clink31 Great! Did you calculate the expected values one by one? Or find out some pattern behind it? (I become can't tell who is OP.) If so why not write an answer by yourself?

Answer (score 2):

In the case of $N \geq M$....

Let $W$ be the winnings after the first $M$ plays. Let $L$ be the number of plays required to win $N$ dollars.

Then $L = M + (N - W)$.

Thus we can compute

$$ E(L) = M + N - E(W) = M + N - \sum_{i=1}^M \frac{i}{M}
= \frac{1}{2}M + N - \frac{1}{2} $$

that is, on average, it takes $\frac{1}{2} M + N - \frac{1}{2}$ plays to win $N$ dollars.

Answer (score 0):

The following works under the assumption $N\geq M$.

The first $M-1$ draws are penalized in some way. Denote by $S(r,n)$ the state when there are still $r$ penalized draws to go and already $n$ dollars are won. Denote by $E(r,n)$ the expected number of additional draws when we are in state $S(r,n)$.

In the first $M-1$ draws one gets at most $M-1$ dollars; therefore  $$E(0,n)=N-n\geq 1\qquad(0\leq n\leq M-1)\ .$$
We are asked to compute $E(M-1,0)$. Now the function $E(\cdot,\cdot)$ satisfies the following recursion:
$$E(r,n)=1+\left(1-{r\over M}\right) E(r-1,n+1) +{r\over M}E(r-1,n)\qquad (r\geq 1,\ n\geq0)\ .$$
It so happens that this recursion is solved by
$$E(r,n)=N-n+{r(r+1)\over 2M}\ .$$
(I found this by computing $E(r,n)$ for $r=1, 2, 3$ and guesswork.) It follows that
$$E(M-1,0)=N+{M-1\over2}\ .$$

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I did for x≥M.

So N = (1/M + 2/M +...+ M/M) + (x - M)

N=(1 + 2 +...+ M )/M + (x - M)

N=(M^2/2 + M/2)/M + (x - M)

N=(M/2 + 1/2) + x - M

So N = -M/2 + x + 1/2

My apologies for not using the fancy equation writing thing. I have no idea how to do that. I would appreciate it so much if someone sent me a link to some sort of guide.